# Create an hidden location for HIstory [firefox]

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, history

I have got a desktop computer XP with Firefox 38.0.1

How to create another location [a second location] for Firefox history so that when someone deletes it closing Firefox automatically and/or cleaning history , it still remains in the other hidden location and the person doesn't realise it?

I mean, I have got someone in my house that uses my computer and signs in to her own Gmail email account and she every time delete the history so that I cannot see anything. Hence, is there a way to turn it around so that I can see the history but she doesn't realise because she of course will see that the history list is empty?

Thank you

Comment: please, tell me whether this question must be posted in Stackoverflow. if so, please i am sorry, feel free to move it.

Comment: Why not create a guest account and ask her to use that?